# Проверка класса динамического массива строк

Tags: массивы, указатели, динамические-массивы, c++

Проверьте пожалуйста код программы, написанный мной по следующему условию:

> Составить описание класса одномерных
> массивов строк, каждая строка задается
> длиной и указателем на выделенную для
> нее память. Предусмотреть возможность
> обращения к отдельным строкам массива
> по индексам, контроль выхода за
> пределы массивов, выполнения операций
> поэлементного сцепления двух массивов
> с образованием нового массива, слияния
> двух массивов с исключением
> повторяющихся элементов, вывод на
> экран элемента массива и всего
> массива. Написать программу,
> демонстрирующую работу с этим классом.
> Программа должна содержать меню,
> позволяющее осуществить проверку всех
> методов класса.

Код:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class StringArray{

    char** string;

    int lenght=0;

    public: StringArray(){

    }

    void addString(char* str){

        this->lenght++;
        char** temp = new char*[this->lenght];

        for (int i = 0; i < this->lenght - 1; i++)
            temp[i] = string[i];

        delete string;
        string = temp;
        string[this->lenght - 1] = str;

    }

    StringArray mergeWith(StringArray a){

        StringArray res = StringArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < this->getLenght(); i++)
            res.addString(this->getString(i));

        for (int i = 0; i < a.getLenght(); i++)
            res.addString(a[i]);

        return res;
    }

    StringArray mergeWith(StringArray a, bool is_unique){

        if (!is_unique) return this->mergeWith(a);

        StringArray res = StringArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < this->getLenght(); i++)
             if (!res.searchString(this->getString(i))) res.addString(this->getString(i));

        for (int i = 0; i < a.getLenght(); i++)
            if (!res.searchString(a.getString(i)))  res.addString(a[i]);

        return res;
    }

    int getLenght(){
        return this->lenght;
    }

    char* getString(int i){

        if (i < this->lenght)
        return  string[i];

        return "Неверный индекс";
    }

    bool searchString(char* str){

        for (int i = 0; i < this->lenght; i++)
            if (this->getString(i) == str)
                return true;

        return false;
    }

    char* operator[](int i){
        return this->getString(i);
    }

    StringArray operator +(StringArray&a){

        return this->mergeWith(a);
    }

friend ostream &operator <<(ostream &out,StringArray &a){
    for (int i = 0; i < a.getLenght(); i++)
        cout << a[i] << endl;

    return out;
    }

};

int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    StringArray arr1 = StringArray();
    arr1.addString("первая");
    arr1.addString("вторая");
    arr1.addString("третья");

    StringArray arr2 = StringArray();
    arr1.addString("третья");
    arr1.addString("четвертая");

    cout << "Первый элемент: " << arr1[0] << endl << "Второй элемент: " << arr1.getString(1) << endl;

    StringArray merged = arr1.mergeWith(arr2,true);

    cout << merged << endl;

    cout << arr1 + arr2 << endl;

    int n;
    cin >> n;
    return 0;
}
```

Какие будут замечания и предложения по коду?  :)

Comment: если найдёте где-нибудь в интернете место, куда можно будет выкладывать код на ревью, поделитесь, буду вам очень благодарен.

Answer (score 2):

1. Функция **addString** реализован ужасно с точки зрения производительности. При добавлении новой строки вы каждый раз стираете удаляете имеющиеся данные и циклом по всем строкам заполняете массив теми же значениями, что в нем были раньше плюс добавляете новую строку. Вопрос - зачем каждый раз делать бесполезную работу (удалять содержимое и писать его заново), при этом в каждом случае проходя по всему массиву. Правильнее было бы создать масси и при добавлении строки писать ее в свободную ячейку массива, а когда массив будет заполнен, выделить новый массив большего размера с копированием в него существующего и последующим удалением существующего.
2. Два цикла в функции **mergeWith** выглядят странно. Достаточно было бы и одного (или может даже вообще какого-нибудь хитрого колдунства с указателями)
3. У вас есть две перегрузки функции **mergeWith**. В обоих присутствует энное количество дублирующейся логики, хотя они отличаются лишь одним параметром. Следовательно, при внесении изменений вам понадобится менять обе. Правильно было бы сделать, чтобы первая перегрузка сводилась к вызову второй с is_unique, равным **false**
4. В случае, если аргумент функции **getString** больше чем размер массива, зачем-то возвращает строку "Неверный индекс". Это ооочень неправильно. По хорошему она должна выкидывать исключение или хотя бы возвращать **NULL**.
5. В этой же функции вы не предусмотрели, что будет, если аргумент будет отрицательным. Также скорее всего случится что-нибудь нехорошее, если передать туда аргумент, равный размеру массива
6. Оператор **operator <<** крашится, если в массиве присутствует **NULL**
7. Я не знаток С++, но по-моему, параметры там лучше передавать с помощью константных ссылок
8. В вашем задании говорится: " каждая строка задается длиной и указателем". Возможно я не заметил, но по-моему, вы нигде не контролируете длины строк, а только длину всего массива

Из мелочей:

1. Ненужный конструктор
2. Название функции **searchString** не интуитивно понятно. Если функция называется **searchString**, то логично, что возвращать она должна строку, а не **bool**. Правильнее было бы назвать ее **contains** или как-то наподобие
3. Правильно писать **length**, а не **lenght**

Comment: 1. ужасно потому что вместо добавления указателя в массив вы перелопачиваете весь массив. Это оч хреново

2. насчет колдунства не подскажу - не знаток крестов, но одним циклом можете обойтись точно - добавляйте данные из второго массива к первому и возвращайте уже его - не будет нужно гонять по обоим массивам

3. Делайте в цикле проверку на флаг. Либо две ветки if с unique и без. Но дублирования логики быть не должно - это большой недостаток

6. Что угодно, что будет работать. Явно лучше, чем получать исключение

8. Нужно или нет, не мне судить, но речь о том, что в задании это требование ест

Comment: >Из мелочей: 2 думаю, будет лучше, если searchString будет возвращать char* со строкой в случае успеха, и NULL в случае, если не найдет такую же строку

насколько я понимаю, вам нужна функция, которая проверяет, есть ли такая строка в вашем массиве. Во всяком случае именно так вы ее используете. В этом случае вам нужно переименовать уже имеющуюся функцию в **contains** и, если есть необходимость, добавить функцию, которая именно ищет строку в массиве, причем желательно, чтобы  первая функция сводилась к вызову второй

Comment: @Ni55aN, уверены, что в `searchString()` Вас интересует именно равенство указателей (т.е. то, что обе строки занимают *одну и ту же память*), а не содержимого?


И еще. В задании ведь явно указано -- "каждая строка задается длиной и указателем на выделенную для нее память".

Так почему не сделали?

Comment: @Ni55aN а можно полюбопытствовать, чем обусловлен ваш минус этому ответу?

Comment: @DreamChild, 1) не стоит гнаться за циферками в строке "Очки уважения"
2) минус соответственно качеству ответа. На другом ресурсе по этому вопросу ответили более качественно, что и говорит о вашем знании С++